# where mongodb exports files?

Tags: mongodb

I am struggling to find the location of the file I am exporting with Mongo, using mongoexport

```
mongoexport --db databaseName --collection collName --out file.json
```

Can someone point me to the location

I run it on ubuntu server with the default installation of mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoexport generates the output file in the current directory

But in case you could not just find a file, I would do something like this:

```
mongoexport --db databaseName --collection collName --out /pathToYourFile/file.json
```

In such a case you will definitely know where it will be. Make sure that you have rights to write in that folder.

Comment: Nope, if you do not specify a file name, the mongo export writes data to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a file name, the mongoexport writes data to standard output.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-out

Answer (score 1):

It will be in your current dir. run `pwd` command on linux machine to see the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mongoexport command will generate the out file in the current directory.